# Advanced join with AND, OR and IS NULL - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to create a query like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM user
INNER JOIN course ON user.course_id = course.id
AND (user.year_from IS NULL OR course.year_from > course.year_from)
AND (user.year_to IS NULL OR course.year_to < course.year_to)
```

My first problem is that I don't know how to translate the IS NULL part. Is it even possible? The second problem is how to get the parentheses right. My first thought was to do something similar to advanced where clauses.

```
$query->join('course', function($join) {
    $join->on(function($join) {
        $join->onNull('user.year_from')->orOn('user.year_from', '>', 'course.year_from');
    };
    $join->on(function($join) {
        $join->onNull('user.year_to')->orOn('user.year_to', '<', 'course.year_to');
    };
});
```

However the `JoinClouse` class doesn't have a method onNull and doesn't support passing a closure as parameter. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked in here http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html? I don't know lavarel, but looking at this page, it seems to me it has your answer. There is a whereNull (http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html#method_whereNull) in there.

Comment: I tried it now and it gave me a `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereNull()`. We are using 4.1 though, maybe it was added in 4.2?

Comment: Anyhow thanks, incentives for upgrading... The other main issue still remains though.

Comment: Right. As an alternative, you can just re-write the SQL. You could have an inner join on matching id's, and have the rest of the conditionals in a where clause. I'm not sure how much that would affect your application though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create that exact query with Laravel methods (unless using raw of course).

Here's what does what you need:

```
$query->join('course', 'user.course_id', '=', 'course.id')
  ->where(function ($q) {
    $q->whereNull('user.year_from')->orWhere('user.year_from', '>', DB::raw('course.year_from'));
  })
  ->where(function ($q) {
    $q->whereNull('user.year_to')->orWhere('user.year_to', '<', DB::raw('course.year_to'));
  });
```

This is the only way Laravel can handle your query, and it's is basically doing exactly the same.

Comment: I actually tried that quickly, but it returned no results so I thought I had to do it in the join clause. After your answer I experimented with some more and after changing the OR queries to `orWhere('user.year_from', '>', DB::raw('course.year_from'))` it started working. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Well, my bad. Of course it's expected behaviour. Changing the answer right away. 2nd/3rd param in `where` is bound, so it's basically treated as a string input, not as a table field. That's why you need to use `raw` for this one.